# Linked List in C++ InsertAtFront

Tags: c++

I am having problems using this code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class node {
    public:
    int data;
    node*next;

    node(int d) {
        int data = d;
        next = NULL;
    }
};
void InsertAtFront(node*&head, int data) {
    node*n = new node(data);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = n;
    } else {
        n->next = head;
        head = n;
    }
}
void print(node*head) {
    node*temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        cout<<temp->data<<"->";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
int main() {
    node*head = NULL;
    InsertAtFront(head,5);
    InsertAtFront(head,4);
    InsertAtFront(head,2);
    InsertAtFront(head,3);
    InsertAtFront(head,1);
    print(head);
}
```

it is giving output

> 0->0->0->0->0->

Why is this so?
It is perfectly working fine when I created a linked list class but it is not working like this.

Comment: It's your constructor that's the problem.

Comment: Why are you reinventing `std::list` ?

Comment: @JVApen: because, sometimes, students are required to implement things they'll never need in real life, to show that they understand the *concepts* involved :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `node` class (specifically, in the constructor):

```
public:
    int data;         // This is your object data.
    node *next;
    node(int d) {
        int data = d; // This data is NOT your object data.
        next=NULL;
    }
```

You are creating a *brand new local* variable called `data` and assigning `d` to it, leaving the *object* `data` variable set to whatever it was before the constructor started. Then your *local* `data` goes out of scope and you then carry on and use your object `data`.

Bottom line, get rid of the `int` at the start of that first line so that it's referring to the correct `data`:

```
node(int d) {
   data = d; // This data IS your object data.
   next=NULL;
}
```

---

And, although that solves your problem, there are a good many things you can still do to improve your code, such as:

- minimise what you bring in to your namespace from libraries (using `std::cout` rather than `using namespace std`)
- realise that a totally public `class` is just a `struct`, and that a mostly public `class` can be built as a `struct` with just a *few* private things at the end;
- use default argument values to allow for flexibility while still keeping things simple (such as allowing the `next` pointer to be specified when constructing a `MyNode`);
- use initialisation rather than code to set member fields as necessary;
- use `nullptr` rather than `NULL`;
- use consistent naming across your code;
- use consistent style (indentations, braces, etc) as well;
- make the list itself a class so that you can easily change the underlying implementation without affecting the API;
- learn to use modern features of C++ such as the range-based `for`.

The following complete program shows your code with those improvements made.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;

struct MyNode {
    int m_data;
    MyNode *m_next;
    MyNode(int data, MyNode *next = nullptr) : m_data(data), m_next(next) {}
};

struct MyList {
    MyList() : m_head(nullptr) {}
    void InsertAtFront(int data) {
        MyNode *node = new MyNode(data, m_head);
        m_head = node;
    }

    void Print() {
        if (m_head == nullptr) {
            cout << "<empty>\n";
            return;
        }
        cout << m_head->m_data;
        MyNode *node = m_head->m_next;
        while (node != NULL) {
            cout << " -> " << node->m_data;
            node = node->m_next;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

private:
    MyNode *m_head;
};

int main() {
    MyList xyzzy;

    for (int x : {5, 4, 2, 3, 1}) {
        xyzzy.InsertAtFront(x);
    }
    xyzzy.Print();
}
```